# Eggs Will "Freeze" and not hatch

Tags: pokemon-go

When walking around town trying to get my eggs to hatch they freeze up every time they move from a x.9 to a x.0 amount.

Example: (An egg that is at a walked distance of 1.9 won't continue to count to 2.0 when walking)

Restarting the game doesn't do anything. About 1-2 days later, I'll get hit with a massive amount of distance walked (usually between 4-7 kilometers) and all the eggs that we're previously frozen will then continue to the "Oh?" screen.

Is there a way I can fix this? I've search several forums and none of them seem to have the exact problem I'm having.

Note: This problem started occurring when the "Appraisal Update" was released.

Edit: The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what sort of phone and operating system you are using?

Comment: This is probably a server-side error that there's nothing you can do to fix, unfortunately. Have you tried closing and restarting the app? Also, just a side note, the egg distance screen doesn't update but every 5 or so minutes, from what I've seen.